# Need to update Test Scripts stored on ALM through AOM

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

I am migrating scripts from BPT framework to Data Driven.

Each QTP Test has same structure (common Library and Object Repository) only QTP Test Name and 4 parameters(*variables- which are testid, testname. test desc, testset*) in Action are changed.

Currently I need to open one existing test and change the aforementioned parameters and "Save As" a new test on ALM (*with new test name and details*)

This is a tedious task when accounted for about 10000 test cases. However, I thought of using ***FSO*** and change the variables under Action of each Test but now the test are not stored on local but on ALM.

I'm trying to create a script which will update and create multiple test case provided from an excel sheet.

Any thoughts on how to go about this ?

Comment: Instead of changing the existing stuff, I would get the list of test names first and create one new UFT test with the new values and clone/copy tests using OTA?

Comment: exactly - I am opening one existing test and copying it ("Save As") with new test name, values etc. I have searched quite a while but I am not able to do this trough OTA or I am messing which method to use in OTA ?- what I intend to do is all the new values should be read from an excel sheet and the opened existing case should be updated (with new values) and "save as" with new name (process repeated for 10000 cases)

Comment: @Barney - Thanks for your help Mate, I was able to formulate a solution - shared below

Answer (score 0):

```
'QC connection

Uname = InputBox ("Enter Username")
Passw = InputBox ("Enter Password")

Set qtApp = CreateObject("quicktest.application")
  if Not qtApp.Visible then
      qtApp.Launch
      qtApp.Visible = True
  End if
  qtApp.Visible = True

qtApp.TDConnection.Connect "https://URL", "BS", "SRP", Uname, Passw, False
If qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then
strQCTestPath = InputBox ("Give full test plan path")
strQCTestPath = "[ALM] " &strQCTestPath
DefScript = InputBox ("Test Script which is to be copied") 'existing test case
almupload = ALMConn(strQCTestPath, DefScript, qtApp)
    if almupload <> "" then
        Msgbox almupload
        Call KL
    Else
        Msgbox "something went wrong"
        Call KL
    End if

Else
    MsgBox "Cannot connect to ALM"
    Flag = False
    Call KL
End If





Function ALMConn(Path, copyscript, qtApp)
Set objexcel = createobject("excel.application")
Set objWorkbook = objexcel.Workbooks.open("C:\book1.xlsx")
Set exceldriver = objWorkbook.worksheets.item("Sheet1")

RC = exceldriver.usedrange.rows.count
CC = exceldriver.usedrange.columns.count
PC = 0
FC = 0
   For i = 2 to RC
      TSid = exceldriver.cells(i,1).value
      TSName = exceldriver.cells(i,2).value
      TCid = exceldriver.cells(i,3).value
      TCName = exceldriver.cells(i,4).value

      'replace the text

      str1 = "FLN"&"("&""""""&")"
      str2 = "TestSetID = " &""""&TSid&""""
      str3 = "TestSetName = "&""""&TSName&""""
      str4 = "TestCaseID = "&""""&TCid&""""
      str5 = "TestCaseName = "&""""&TCName&""""
      str6 = "Call ExecuteTestCase"&"("&"TestSetID"&","&"TestSetName"&","&"TestCaseID"&","&"TestCaseName"&")"
    finalstr = str1 &VbCrlf &VbCrlf& str2 &VbCrlf& str3 &VbCrlf& str4 &VbCrlf& str5 &VbCrlf &VbCrlf& str6
    Almtestname =TCid &" "&TCName 

    sFlag = UpdateScript(Path, finalstr, copyscript, Almtestname, qtApp)
    if sFlag = True then
        exceldriver.cells(i,5).value = "Pass"
        PC = PC +1
    Else
        exceldriver.cells(i,5).value = "Fail"
        FC = FC +1
    End if

Next
    finalcount = "Passcount is "&PC &VbCrlf& "Fail Count is "&FC
    ALMConn = finalcount
    objWorkbook.Save
    objexcel.quit
    qtApp.TDConnection.Disconnect
End Function

Function UpdateScript(Path, sfinalstr, refscript, Tname, qtApp)
'On error resume next
'Err.Clear
  If qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then
      oPath = Path &"\"&refscript
      qtApp.Open oPath, False
  '   if err.number>0 then
'        UpdateScript = False
'        ExitFunction
'     Else
         '"[ALM] Subject\Delete\1\GUITest1", False '"C:\Local Disk\New Folder\GUITest1"
          oldtext = qtApp.Test.Actions(1).GetScript
'     End if
 Else
     Msgbox "not connected"
     UpdateScript = False
     ExitFunction
 End if

If oldtext <> "" then
    qtApp.Test.Actions(1).SetScript(sfinalstr)
    qtApp.Test.SaveAs Path &"\"&Tname       '"C:\Local Disk\New Folder\GUITest2"
    if Err.Number>0 then
        UpdateScript = False
        ExitFunction
    Else
        UpdateScript = True
    End if
Else
    UpdateScript = False
End if
End Function



Function KL
  Set qtApp = Nothing
  exceldriver = Nothing
  objWorkbook = Nothing
  objexcel = Nothing
End Function
```